# How to flash a bitstream file in a PROM on Digilent Xilinx FPGA board, using scripts?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am using the excellent open-source [FPGALink](http://www.makestuff.eu/wordpress/software/fpgalink/) utility to program a FPGA, through USB and JTAG.

Classically, I generate a .bit file correctly, using a set of scripts gluing the various stages of the Xilinx synthesis process.

That works like a charm : just after the bitstream has been loaded into FPGA, I can play with my embedded design on a [Nexys2 FPGA board](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=NEXYS2) (from Digilent).

However, now I am facing a new challenge : I'd like to flash my .bit file into the PROM. It seems I need to generate a .mcs file now. I found a [tutorial](https://wiki.trenz-electronic.de/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10617444) but it focuses on Xilinx GUI, that I really want to avoid.

How can I manage to do this, only based on scripts ? (update : this [link](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/pim_r_examples.htm) seems to give a detailed procedure)

And then how to load this in PROM, using FPGALink ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that everything is explained [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fpgalink-users/vDR7095EcZM).